# How do I make Visual Studio 2012 always open source files on second monitor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to improve how I use VS on multiple monitors. I want to have Solution explorer, team explorer and all my error windows, deployment windows, package explorer etc on one monitor.

I want any files I am editing to open up maximized on second monitor.

I can easily move a source file and make it full screen on second monitor but any new files I double click on in the source explorer always open in a tiny pane on first monitor with my solution explorer etc.

This explains how to open a second solution explorer and dock it with my source control file http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/09/05/working-with-multiple-solution-explorer-windows-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

So I can use that to open files in the second window. However I wanted the source control file full screen so wanted the solution explorer only in the main Visual Studio and only to have one.

This is probably obvious but seem to be missing how to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way but you could try to move your main window to the 2nd monitor and move all of the other panels out of the actual vs window onto your first monitor.

Comment: I want everything that isn't source files e.g. Menus, toolbars etc on one screen so wanted only source file with no menus etc on the second monitor